# standalone war / java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, war, desktop-application

i have prepared a web application using netbeans, i want to share this with the client where he can unzip folder and has an icon to click and start using it , how can i achieve this where run time environment or anything that is required by a web application get packaged as a zip to download and run on any computer.

i have checked the below link but it doesnt help much as there is no maven used  :

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/standalone-web-application-with-executable-tomcat.html

Comment: I would use Spring-boot http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: What do you mean by 'no maven used'? Do you not use maven to build your project? Would you like to use netbeans to generate an executable war?

Comment: Yes Mare , i have not used maven to build the project. I simply add a single mysql jar that was required.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a embedded server like [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

1. Create a main method.
2. Create manifest file.
3. Bundle them into an executable jar.

These steps are explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/).

In the main method you need to start jetty programmatically and add the wars to it.

```
   Server server = new Server(8088);

   WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
   webapp.setWar("location to war");
   webapp.setContextPath("/contextpath");
   server.setHandler(webapp);

   server.start();
```

EDIT:

To bundle java runtime, a cleaner approach would be using [JNLP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html).

Comment: That does not include the most important part of the "runtime environment" though - the Java runtime itself. Nor does this include the installation of the MySQL database that is only mentioned in the comments.